# Integrate MobilePay in Xamrain app (IOS version)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, deep-linking

I am creating a project in **Xamarin** and in that, I want to use [MobilePay](https://mobilepaydev.github.io/MobilePay-Payments-API/docs/introduction) as a payment option. And I have checked many more references and videos about the implementation and I'll complete the **android** version(with the deep link) but I can't able to do it for the IOS version

Can you please get me some idea about these things, How to pass data and receive data from the app delegate (controller to appdelegate file)

I have implemented it in android and ios also I'll go with platform-specific
[image]

Below the image, I get the response in the android version after the complete the payment process from the MobilePay
[image]

But when I am implementing IOS I'll use UIApplication(**[UIKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/uikit/)** package) and it also works but when the app center generate build APK (after committing code) for the android it's getting me below error
[image]

means it's the effect on the android app building

I don't have an idea how to **pass data controller to app delegate** file and use response data that getting from the google pay response